# How to reload an embedded page, from within that embedded page, without reloading the 'container' page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have run into a problem, and I am not sure how to resolve this, or if it can be. In my HTML/PHP page, a have a search form. When the user searches for something, instead of passing control to another page, I'm using jquery to load another php page into a div container to perform the query and display results. The problem I've run into is in terms of sorting the results. The way I generally handle sorting, is just to build the URL string containing the new sort parameters, and execute/load that URL, which is the same page, just different sort parameters. But with the page that does the query being embedded into another page, I need to reload that page in the containing page's div. But since I'm inside the embedded page, I have no access to that page's elements.

```
<!-- ======================== Container Page =============================== -->
<div class="row search-form-container" id="search-scripts-container">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-group input-append date" data-provide="datepicker">
      <span class="input-group-addon add-on">FROM</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="script_from_date"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="input-group input-append date" data-provide="datepicker">
      <span class="input-group-addon add-on">TO</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="script_to_date"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- search all input box -->
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="input-group input-append">
      <span class="input-group-addon addon">SEARCH</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="script_search_all" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sbmt_scripts_search">Query</button>
  </div>
</div>



//===================== JQuery Function ===============================

$('#sbmt_scripts_search').click(function() {
     var from_date = $('#script_from_date').val();
     var to_date = $('#script_to_date').val();
     var search_str = $('#script_search_all').val().replace(/\ /g, '_'); // convert spaces to underscores to pass in url
     $('#results-container').load('/search/results.php?from_date='+from_date+'&to_date='+to_date+'&search_str='+search_str+'&col=0&order=DESC');
 });



//============================ PHP Results Page ============================
  Create and execute query....

  // selection list to select field to sort by
  <div class="row" style="margin:40px 0 5px 0">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-9" align="right">
            <label for="col_sort">Sort By:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:0;">
            <select class="sort_select" id="col_sort" style="width:100%; padding:0; margin:0;">
                <option value="/search/prescription_results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=0&order=<?=$sort_args[0]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
                <option <?=($col == 1) ? "selected='selected'" : ""?> value="/search/results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=1&order=<?=$sort_args[1]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
                <option <?=($col == 2) ? "selected='selected'" : ""?> value="/search/results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=2&order=<?=$sort_args[2]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
                <option <?=($col == 3) ? "selected='selected'" : ""?> value="/search/results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=3&order=<?=$sort_args[3]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
                <option <?=($col == 4) ? "selected='selected'" : ""?> value="/search/results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=4&order=<?=$sort_args[4]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
                <option <?=($col == 5) ? "selected='selected'" : ""?> value="/search/results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=5&order=<?=$sort_args[5]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
                <option <?=($col == 6) ? "selected='selected'" : ""?> value="/search/results.php?from_date=<?=$from_date?>&to_date=<?=$to_date?>&search_str=<?=$search_string?>&col=6&order=<?=$sort_args[6]['order']?>">
                    Data
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
</div>

  // display query results
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <a href="/view.php?rx=<?=base64_encode($data['number'])?>">data#<?=$data?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>
              <strong>Data:</strong> <?=$result1?><br/>
              <strong>Data:</strong> <?=$result2?><br/>
              <strong>Data:</strong> <?=$result3?><br/>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>
              <strong>Data:</strong> <?=$result4?><br/>         
              <strong>Data:</strong> <?=$result5?><br/>
              <strong>Data:</strong> <?=$result6?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
```

Here is the basics of what's going on.. When someone selects a header to sort by, I want to reload the php page, with the new sort arguments, without reloading the outer or container page.

```
//========================= PHP Query ================================
SELECT presc.*, doc.first_name as doctor_fname, doc.last_name as doctor_lname, prov.name as provider_name
FROM `PRESCRIPTIONS` presc
JOIN `DOCTORS` doc
  ON presc.doctor_id = doc.id
LEFT JOIN `PROVIDERS` prov
  ON presc.provider_id = prov.id
WHERE presc.patient_fname LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.patient_lname LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR CONCAT_WS(' ', presc.patient_fname, presc.patient_lname) LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.date_of_birth LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.script_date LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.drug LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.rx_number LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.status LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.ticket_date LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.adherence_pct LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR presc.nursing_home LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR doc.first_name LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR doc.last_name LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat."
   OR prov.name LIKE '%$search_string%'
  AND".$date_concat;"
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pass all those sorting flags through your jquery function to the page doing the searching?

Comment: the page that is loaded into the div, performs the query, and displays the results in a table. So if a user clicks on that table header, it will reload the page, and sort the the results based on the column they clicked on. Which all that is cool. But I need to do this, without reloading the 'container' page. I just want to reload the embedded page itself... But i can't call the load function on the container div, because I am no longer 'in' that page.

Comment: sounds like you want to look into AJAX, it looks like you're sorta trying to fake an AJAX call right now.  AJAX is an extremely powerful method of updating sections of a page from a server.  I would take a  look at this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yeah, i know AJAX, but i don't know if that would solve this though. Or atleast I'm not thinking of it

Comment: Should definitely be using AJAX, see my rough example usage in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using AJAX to do this. Below is a very rough usage. You'll note that the function `getDataFromDataBaseOrWhatever` in the PHP I expect to return HTML formatted correctly to simply display on the client. This is one way to do it, however you could consider simply returning an object with the values you want, and then use the `success` function in the JS to use that object to then build the HTML itself. This is usually the better approach as the PHP should be simply handling data, and the client should be in control of the view (HTML).

However I've done it the first way below so its not so much of a jump for you. If you want an example of the other way, also, let me know.

```
// JS 

$.ajax({  
    url: 'script.php',  
    type:'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        action: 'search',
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate
        // other filters
    },
    success: function(res){  
        if(res.success) {
            $('#results-container').html(res.html);
        } else {
            // error with script or server
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
        error with request/server
    },
});



// PHP

$data = $_POST['data'];
if($data['action'] != 'search') {
    die('wrong action');
}

// make sure params are what you might expect for security

// setup our query function
// using HTML output by server
function getDataFromDataBaseOrWhatever() {


    return $html;
}

// create return object
$return = new stdClass();

// use data from POST
$startDate = $data['startDate'];

// get return values/HTML
$return->html = getDataFromDataBaseOrWhatever();

// if everything is okay, set the res property to true
$return->success = true;

die(json_encode($return));
```

Comment: Right on, that makes much more sense than my method.. Thank you.

Comment: If you get this working, I strongly suggest you try and figure out the second way I described! Good luck!

Comment: How would you go about displaying that data in a table, or anything along those lines, with this method? Considering the receiving page does not know anything about the result set.

Comment: The only part i don't completely understand is, '$return->html = getFromDB();'. How is this, or how can this, retrieve, or create the html necessary for displaying the data?

Comment: What are you doing exactly to get the data you are wanting? Eg where is `$data` coming from?

Comment: currently, It's coming from a query to a couple tables in the DB, in  the same php  page as the code you posted would be in.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of these queries and what they might return and I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: I just posted one instance of the query under the question. So that query would be executed then the results would be displayed in the HTML that's posted in the question under '==== PHP Results Page ===='

Comment: And then there is a selection list with the table fields in it.. My intention is, when a particular field is selected from the dropdown, it reloads that page/data, displaying the data sorted by the row selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72379/discussion-between-anacy-and-nick-m).